# in scala, how to create a list of immutable objects with references among them?

Tags: scala

The following example builds a set of persons, with family links between them.

```
  case class Person(id: Int, name: String, father: Option[Int], mother: Option[Int], children: Set[Int])

  val john = Person(0, "john", None, None, Set(2))
  val maria = Person(1, "maria", None, None, Set(2))
  val georges = Person(2, "georges", Some(0), Some(1), Set.empty)

  val people = Set(john, maria, georges)
  val peopleMap = people.map(p => (p.id, p)).toMap

  val meanChildrenSize = people.map(p => p.children.map(peopleMap).size).sum.toDouble / people.size
```

The example works ok, but I don't like that I need to build this extra `peopleMap` and call `p.children.map(peopleMap)` as it makes it difficult to read. I would prefer to model the example as follows:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String, father: Option[Person], mother: Option[Person], children: Set[Person])

val john = Person(1, "john", None, None, Set.empty)
val maria = Person(2, "maria", None, None, Set.empty)
val georges = Person(3, "georges", Some(john), Some(maria), Set.empty)

val people = Set(john, maria, georges)

val meanChildrenSize = people.map(p => p.children.size).sum.toDouble / people.size
```

However, the problem now is that john and maria cannot initialize the children set as georges is still not created. How to solve this (preferably using immutable case classes)?

---

**Update**:
someone proposed to use `lazy`:

```
  case class Person(id: Int, name: String, father: Option[Person], mother: Option[Person], children: Set[Person])

  lazy val john: Person = Person(1, "john", None, None, Set(georges))
  lazy val maria: Person = Person(2, "maria", None, None, Set(georges))
  lazy val georges: Person = Person(3, "georges", Some(john), Some(maria), Set.empty)
```

this fails with a StackOverflowError.

Comment: Why not create `georges` first, and then bind `john` and `maria` from the references created inside `georges`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more lazyness will help. Let's start with extreme case:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String, father: () => Option[Person], mother: () => Option[Person], children: () => Set[Person])

lazy val john = Person(1, "john", () => None, () => None, () => Set.empty)
lazy val maria = Person(2, "maria", () => None, () => None, () => Set.empty)
lazy val georges = Person(3, "georges", () => Some(john), () => Some(maria), () => Set.empty)

val people = Set(john, maria, georges)
```

Experiment:

```
val meanChildrenSize = people.map(p => p.children().size).sum.toDouble / people.size 
meanChildrenSize: Double = 0.0
```

This will let you avoid loops in relationships but might destroy "equals" contract (having loops in data will destroy naive `equals`-approach and cause StackOverflow, so it's better to not implement it for function0 `() => ...` members) - see examples below. It will also cause re-evaluation problem as well (which is solvable with call-by-name from @srjd-approach, however that approach might stack-overflow equality in case of `def max: Person = Person(1, "aaa", None, None, Set(max)); max == max`).

So, more practical approach is:

```
case class Person(id: Int, name: String, father: Option[Person], mother: Option[Person], children: Set[Person])

lazy val john = Person(1, "john", None, None, Set.empty)
lazy val maria = Person(2, "maria", None, None, Set.empty)
lazy val georges = Person(3, "georges", Some(john), Some(maria), Set.empty)

val people = Set(john, maria, georges)
```

Experiment yields same result. However, some complex cross-dependencies might cause problems, depending on the order of initialization inside `people` set (I should mention that any order works for your current example and my random non-loop modifications of your data).

Or as @YuvalItzchakov suggested - you could initialize `georges` first, but it's less scalable as you would have to care about initialization order.

The example when `lazy val` approach doesn't work:

```
//John is his own child now (almost like Fry from Futurama)
lazy val john: Person = Person(1, "john", None, None, Set(john))
val people = Set(georges,john, maria) 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

So if you expect some loops in your data - it's better to use "extreme" approach presented above:

```
...
//John is his own child now
lazy val john: Person = Person(1, "john", () => None, () => None, () => Set(john))
val people = Set(john, maria, georges)
```

Experiment:

```
val meanChildrenSize = people.map(p => p.children().size).sum.toDouble / people.size 
meanChildrenSize: Double = 0.3333333333333333
```

So the result is correct, but if you manually override equals to account for father/mother/children members - it would yield stack-overflow. Your model suggests equality by id, so you could use just smthng like that:

```
 case class Person(id: Int, name: String, father: () => Option[Person], mother: () => Option[Person], children: () => Set[Person]){
   override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
     case Person(id2, name2, _, _, _) => id == id2 && name == name2
     case _ => false
   }
   //You might not need to override hashCode (if you're not gonna put data as a key into some big dictionaries) as `equals` is stronger
   override def hashCode = (id, name).hashCode
 }
```

Example:

```
 val a = Person(1, "john", () => None, () => None, () => Set()) == Person(1, "john", () => None, () => None, () => Set()) 
 val b = a

 @ Map(a -> "a", b -> "b") 
 res55: Map[Person, String] = Map(Person(1, "john", <function0>, <function0>, <function0>) -> "b")
 @ res55(a) 
 res56: String = "b"
 @ res55(b) 
 res57: String = "b"
```

Without `override hashCode` - res55-Map would have two elements instead of one. You might need to "override" apply/unapply too (as @sjrd suggested) in order to avoid `function0`-members (or just ignore them in pattern matching with `_`). Btw, you could adapt this weak equality to @srjd approach as well.

As a conclusion, if you construct your data from some text-representation or database - you can rely on "non-loopness" of external model (or check it at validation stage) and avoid that "extreme" approach at all.

P.S. Be careful with lazy val's, they actually have "synchronized" inside (it should change in new versions of Scala, but not in Scala 2.11.x at least), so deadlocks are possible in complex cases - generally, I'd recommend to avoid any manual locks inside `lazy val`.

---

Update (in respond to question's update):

In the case when you need to have parents/children two-side linked (loops), you can combine both solutions:

```
final case class Person(id: Int, name: String, father: Option[Person], mother: Option[Person], children: () => Set[Person]){
  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case Person(id2, name2, _, _, _) => id == id2 && name == name2
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode = (id, name).hashCode
}


lazy val john = Person(1, "john", None, None, () => Set(georges))
lazy val maria = Person(2, "maria", None, None, () => Set(georges))
lazy val georges: Person = Person(3, "georges", Some(john), Some(maria), () => Set.empty)

val people = Set(john, maria, georges)

val meanChildrenSize = people.map(_.children().size).sum.toDouble / people.size

meanChildrenSize: Double = 0.3333333333333333
```

You might notice that your approach does take account for duplicate children' sizes(!), so maybe you need this:

```
val meanChildrenSize = people.toList.map(_.children().size).sum.toDouble / people.size
meanChildrenSize: Double = 0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: i don't see how this solves the problem. john.children.size is still 0, and it should be one (georges).

Comment: thx, answer accepted. here it goes a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724708/in-scala-how-to-create-a-list-of-immutable-objects-with-references-among-them

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this problem with completely immutable case classes, because you need `lazy val`s to create circular dependencies in immutable data structures.

Here is one way to define your `Person` class that provides the API you want:

```
class Person(val id: Int, val name: String, father0: => Option[Person], mother0: => Option[Person], children0: => Set[Person]) {
  lazy val father = father0
  lazy val mother = mother0
  lazy val children = children0

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case Person(this.id, this.name, this.father, this.mother, this.children) => true
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode(): Int = { ... }
}

object Person {
  def apply(id: Int, name: String, father0: => Option[Person], mother0: => Option[Person], children0: => Set[Person]): Person =
    new Person(id, name, father0, mother0, children0)

  def unapply(p: Person): Some[(Int, String, Option[Person], Option[Person], Set[Person])] =
    Some(p.id, p.name, p.father, p.mother, p.children)
}
```

The fact that you cannot directly use a case class means that you have quite some amount of boilerplate to write, unfortunately.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? I have noticed a nasty habit here lately of downvoting answers that don't provide code that is ready to be copy pasted without a second thought.

Comment: i don't see how this solves the problem. how do you initialize the 3 persons?

Comment: `lazy val john: Person = ...`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think @srjd's answer though not complete and has problems, is a step in right direction.

As for a more complete working solution, you can use this,

```
class Person(id: Int, name: String, mother: => Option[Person], father: => Option[Person], children: => Set[Person]) {
  def getId = id
  def getName = name
  def getMother = mother
  def getFather = father
  def getChildren = children

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case Person(tId, tName, tMother, tFather, tChildren) => {
      id == tId && name == tName && mother == tMother && father == tFather && children == tChildren
    }
    case _ => false
  }

  // you will want a better hashcode method
  override def hashCode(): Int = List(id, name).hashCode()

}

object Person {

  def apply(id: Int, name: String, mother: => Option[Person], father: => Option[Person], children: => Set[Person]): Person =
    new Person(id, name, mother, father, children)

  def unapply(p: Person): Option[(Int, String, Option[Person], Option[Person], Set[Person])] =
    Some((p.getId, p.getName, p.getFather, p.getMother, p.getChildren))
}
```

Now you can use this like following,

```
lazy val father: Person = Person(1, "father", None, None, Set(son))

lazy val mother: Person = Person(2, "mother", None, None, Set(son))

lazy val son: Person = Person(2, "son", Some(father), Some(mother), Set.empty[Person])

val people = Set[Person](father, mother, son)

val totalChildrenSize1 = people
  .map({
    case Person(id, name, mother, father, children) => children.size
  })
  .sum
  .toDouble

// Or
val totalChildrenSize2 = people
  .map(p => p.getChildren.size)
  .sum
  .toDouble

val meanChildrenSize1 = totalChildrenSize1 / people.size
// Or
val meanChildrenSize2 = totalChildrenSize2 / people.size
```

Comment: This actually has more problems. `mother` will get reevaluated every time you call `getMother`.

Comment: @Jasper-M if you did not read both answers then please read now and try to notice that both approaches are same in that aspect. This answer is just a more complete problem-free improvement over sjrd's answer. And just how much of an overhead will that add ? As `mother` is just `=> instance`. Keep in mind that the normal getters are also `() => instance`. And why was this down-voted ? Anyone ?

Comment: It is not only about overhead. Also about side effects.

Comment: Well... side effects are the bane of Scala FP. Almost any FP construct in Scala can be deemed as unsafe with the `possibility of introducing side effects`

Comment: @Jasper-M And the way I think about StackOverFlow... down-votes should be used when you see a major problem with an answer to the point of being un-acceptable. Up-votes when you like something an an answer. And in other cases the answers should be left alone.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer but I agree it has a problem.

Comment: I wish StackOverFlow makes down-voting such that the first 3 down-votes require comment stating the reason or proposed improvement.