# in scala, how to create a list of immutable objects with references among them (when instances not know in advance)?

Tags: scala

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717310/280393 explains how to create a list of immutable objects with references among them; However, the solution provided requires the objects to be known in advance.
How to achieve this when the objects are created on demand?

```
  case class PersonA(id: Int, name: String, friends: Set[Int])
  val john = PersonA(0, "john", Set(1,2))
  val maria = PersonA(1, "maria", Set(0))
  val georges = PersonA(2, "georges", Set(1))
  val peopleA = Set(john, maria, georges)

  case class PersonB(id: Int, name: String, friends: Set[PersonB])
  // case class PersonB(id: Int, name: String, friends: () => Set[PersonB])

  def convert(peopleA: Set[PersonA]): Set[PersonB] = ???

  val peopleB = convert(peopleA)

  println(peopleB)
  println(peopleB.toList.map(_.friends.size))
  peopleB.toList.map {
    case PersonB(id, name, friends) => friends.size
  }.foreach(println)
```

So, without modifying the implementation of `case class PersonA` and `val peopleA`, how to implement `convert`?

assuming that two `PersonB` instances are equal iff their `id` is equal,
one solution would be like this:

```
class PersonB(val id: Int, val name: String) {
  var friends0: Set[PersonB] = _
  def setFriends(friends: Set[PersonB]) {
    require(friends0 == null)
    friends0 = friends
  }
  def friends: Set[PersonB] = {
    require(friends0 != null)
    friends0
  }

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case t: PersonB => t.id == id
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode(): Int = id.hashCode

  override def toString = s"PersonB($id, $name, List(${friends.map(_.id).mkString(", ")}))"
}

object PersonB {
  def apply(id: Int, name: String) = new PersonB(id, name)
  def apply(id: Int, name: String, friends: Set[PersonB]): PersonB = {
    val p = new PersonB(id, name)
    p.setFriends(friends)
    p
  }

  def unapply(p: PersonB): Option[(Int, String, Set[PersonB])] =
    Some((p.id, p.name, p.friends))
}

def convert(peopleA: Set[PersonA]): Set[PersonB] = {
  val peopleB = peopleA.map(p => new PersonB(p.id, p.name))
  val peopleBMap = peopleB.map(p => (p.id, p)).toMap
  peopleA.foreach(p =>
    peopleBMap(p.id).setFriends(p.friends.map(peopleBMap))
  )
  peopleB
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

---

**Udate** Solution based on @sjrd answer:

```
class PersonB(val id: Int, val name: String, friends0: => Set[PersonB]) {
  lazy val friends: Set[PersonB] = friends0

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = that match {
    case t: PersonB => t.id == id
    case _ => false
  }

  override def hashCode(): Int = id.hashCode

  override def toString = s"PersonB($id, $name, List(${friends.map(_.id).mkString(", ")}))"
}

object PersonB {
  def apply(id: Int, name: String, friends: => Set[PersonB]): PersonB =
    new PersonB(id, name, friends)

  def unapply(p: PersonB): Option[(Int, String, Set[PersonB])] =
    Some((p.id, p.name, p.friends))
}

def convert(peopleA: Set[PersonA]): Set[PersonB] = {
  lazy val peopleB: Map[Int, PersonB] =
    (for (PersonA(id, name, friendsIDs) <- peopleA)
      yield (id, PersonB(id, name, friendsIDs.map(peopleB)))).toMap

  peopleB.values.toSet
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this definition of `PersonB`:

```
case class PersonB(id: Int, name: String, friends: () => Set[PersonB])
```

you can write:

```
def convert(peopleA: Set[PersonA]): Set[PersonB] = {
  lazy val peopleB: Map[Int, PersonB] =
    (for (PersonA(id, name, friendsIDs) <- peopleA)
      yield PersonB(id, name, () => friendsIDs.map(peopleB)).toMap
  peopleB.values.toSet
}
```

Not tested, but something close to this should work.

Comment: thx! i've modified a bit your answer and added it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create immutable data you need to have a DAG / directed acyclic graph for creation order of you objects.

I do not think that you can do this since just the first 2 records have a cycle:

```
val john = PersonB(0, "john", Set(maria, ...))
val maria = PersonB(1, "maria", Set(john))
```

john is dependent on maria and maria on john.
So john is has to be created after maria and maria be created after john.

So you might have to compromise with your immutable data structures and not use case class but maybe an assign once instead.